# TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is undefined in selfinvoked function

Tags: javascript

So I read after this error and apparently there is a semicolon missing?
But I simply can't figure out where exactly:

```
 <script>
  (() => {
    fetch('/testmode')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(body => {
        console.log('testmode:', body);
        if (body) {
          document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = "favicon.test.ico";
        } else {
          document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = "favicon.ico";
        };
    });
  })().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  </script>
```

I placed the semicolon almost everywhere already to find out where it could be missing but I just won't work.

Any idea what I am missing here? Funnily enough when I write async ()... then the error disappears but I can't use async as it's not supported by all browsers.

thanks

Comment: You are not returning the fetch promise to attach the catch to

Comment: `fetch` <-- missing return statement. You are returing `undefined`.

Comment: Write the code with async, then use a transpiler.

Comment: `there is a semicolon missing?`  What led you to that conclusion.?

Comment: @Keith it's pretty common for expressions starting with a `(` to erroneously be interpreted as a function invocation on the previous expression if it was missing a semicolon, due to how ASI fails to kick in on newlines before a `(` token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no semicolon missing. You've just misplaced the `catch` invocation, it should go directly on the promise chain:

```
fetch('/testmode').then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(body => {
  console.log('testmode:', body);
  document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = body
    ? "favicon.test.ico"
    : "favicon.ico";
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

You don't even need the IIFE here - there are no local variables to be protected. If you still want to use one, either wrap the whole thing:

```
(() => {
  fetch('/testmode').then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(body => {
    console.log('testmode:', body);
    document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = body
      ? "favicon.test.ico"
      : "favicon.ico";
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
})();
```

or **return** the intermediate value:

```
(() => {
  return fetch('/testmode').then(response => {
//^^^^^^
    return response.json();
  }).then(body => {
    console.log('testmode:', body);
    document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = body
      ? "favicon.test.ico"
      : "favicon.ico";
  });
})().catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```